# Using Spring AOP with Quartz scheduler

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler for scheduling purposes in my project. I need to gather statistics like when, for how long, and how many times a job was run. I want to use Spring AOP for the same. For this, I am making Job classes spring-managed beans. Spring creates a Proxy class for each of the Job classes. But now when Quartz tries to execute this spring-managed Job, I am getting InstantiationException for the Proxy class created for the Job by Spring.

> org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class '$Proxy6'
>   [See nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException: $Proxy6]

Can anybody please suggest a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use quarz directly (not via Spring Schedule annotation), you can ask quarz directly for the statistics. -- Many of them are already implemented in quarz.

Answer (score 1):

Because Quartz Job class is managed by Quartz container not Spring container, Spring AOP can not achieve your goal. For your purpose, there are 2 ways that you can work on this:

1. Quartz has listener mechanism builtin, you can use a global listener to do want you want, as the AOP works. For more information about listener, refer to: [Quartz document](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigListeners.html).
2. If you insist on Spring AOP, you have to customize the job class instantiation process, so that the job class is managed by Spring Container. One approach is write your own JobFactory, which extends `SpringBeanJobFactory` then override the `createJobInstance()` method. If you want more things about this, please comment on this, I will write more detail on this.

Comment: Hello, I'm very interested in hearing more about the extension of SpringBeanJobFactory and being able to use Spring Aspects. Can you explain a bit or point me to some useful documentation? Thanks